# Dictionary Renderer, Text symbol

Tags: .net

I have a working stylx file that renders the symbols as expected. I noticed when working with arcgis PRO that I can add text symbols to the db and gave it a unique key.
The problem is that i can't manage to get the text symbol (as a label) on the runtime

I tried using the text keys in the configuration section on the meta table